# How to get the filename of a dragged file (before drop)

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I would like to get the file extension of a file that is dragged from **outside the browser**.
Looking through many tutorials and questions/answers on StackOverflow I just don't seem to find the answer (or I'm just to stupid to search the correct terms).

I know that you can access the filename within the `ondrop` event, but I want to react depending on the file type the user is dragging into my application before he drops the file. There's has to be some way, because Webflow (a web app to build responsive websites) is doing just that. Depending on the file type it gives you a different type of element.

I'm thankful for every little lead in the right direction

Comment: `event.dataTransfer.files[n].type` will contain the MIME type of the file being uploaded, e.g. `image/png` or `text/plain`, and `event.dataTransfer.files[n].name` will contain the file name.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working in the `dragover` event, only in the `drop` event and this is what i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it during the dragover event, your only option is the MIME type, which can be retrieved with `event.dataTransfer.items[n].type`. The rest of the file's information is inaccessible until the drop event.

Be aware of [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/items#Browser_compatibility) for this feature, as Internet Explorer and Safari both don't support this.

```js
var dropReceiver = document.getElementById("dropReceiver");

dropReceiver.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    
    for(var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.items.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.items[i].type);
    }
});
```

```css
#dropReceiver
{
padding: 100px 120px;
background: blue;
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropReceiver">Drag On Me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect! You've made my day :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: This answer was really helpful although it says 'n' is undefined, ie event.dataTransfer.items[n].type, so you might want to change [n] to [0]. That worked for me